# Android Studio Commander Popup change order

Tags: android-studio, ide

I was wondering. Is there any possibility to change order of options after pressing `Alt+Insert` (New...) in `Project Structure` tab. I'm not sure if it's called Commander Popup, but I meant this:

[image]

I really want to have `Kotlin File/Class` as my first option. I was trying to change some options in `Menus and Toolbars` setting like this:

[image]

But unfortunately it changes nothing.

I know I can assign shortcut to generate new Kotlin File - but it feels like workaround.